# ZF2, Route with ID or action in the same place?

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I want this route:

```
localhost/users/1 -> show profile  
localhost/users/ -> show list users  
localhost/users/anyaction -> execute any action in UsersController.php
localhost/users/anyaction/23 -> execute any action, with optional parameters(23), in UsersController.php
```

How do I write this in module.config.php with Zend Framework 2?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html

Comment: Please can you *answer* your question with the soultion, rather than edit the question with it. People like myself get confused. You will also then able to be accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create child route for the actions, and in the route main only ID numeric.

```
'router'=>array(
'routes'=>array(
    'users'=>array(
        'type'=>'Segment',
        'options'=>array(
            'route' => '/users[/:id]',
            'constraints'  => array ( 
                'id'      =>  '[0-9]+' , 
            ), 
            'defaults'  =>  array(
                'controller' => 'Users\Controller\Users',
                'action'     => 'index'
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'action' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '[/[:action[/:id]]]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Users\Controller\Users',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is

```
'routes'=>array(
        'users'=>array(
            'type'=>'Segment',
            'options'=>array(
                'route' => '/users[/:id][/:action]',
                'constraints' => array( 
                    'id' => '[0-9]*', 
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*' 
                ),
                'defaults'  =>  array(
                    'controller' => 'Users\Controller\Users',
                    'action'     => 'index'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

But **users/anyaction** not work

**users//anyaction** work, with double slash.